# How to execute code at the end of a casperjs script

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm trying to have a casper script time itself, to do this I'm setting a variable at the beginning and end by Date().getTime(), then using console.log to print the difference. The problem I have is that the lines at the end of the script get executed before casper does any work.

I'm not very experienced with JavaScript and do realize that out of order completion can improve the performance of a lot of tasks, but the various casper wait methods don't seem applicable.

Comment: Your code has a number of callbacks, you have to add a timer to the one that gets called last. There may be an event that tells you the script completed, but I haven't found it

Comment: You may be able to use the [run.complete event](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#run-complete)

Comment: @JuanMendes That's it. `run.start` and `run.complete` events are what OP needs. You may want to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation indicates that the [run.complete](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#run-complete) event fires after all the steps in a run are complete.

*Arguments: None*

- Emitted when the whole series of steps in the stack have been executed

Comment: casper.on('run.complete', function() { ... });